# PDO not substituting parameters properly

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm making a blog based on PHP and MySQL (using PDO to connect). I have written a function (below) that will retrieve blog posts and return them, but `order by` isn't working when I pass it by reference:

```
<?php
/**
 * Get blog posts, filtered and sorted to taste.
 * @return array Array of rows - each row is an array indexed by column name.
 * @param string $inFunction What to select posts by - id, date or tag(s).
 * @param string $inFilter Filter data to select posts by - id no., date(s) or tag(s). If you are filtering by date and only specify one, it will be taken to be the 'newer than' date.
 * @param string $inOrder How to sort posts. This parameter is fed directly into the query and therefore should be raw SQL.
 * @param object $inDatabase Database handle to pass to the SQL query.
 */

function getBlogPosts($inFunction, $inDatabase, $inFilter, $inOrder) {
    switch ($inFunction) {
        case "permalink": {
            $query = $inDatabase->prepare("select * from blog_posts where permalink = :permalink");
            $query->bindValue(":permalink", $inFilter);
            $query->execute();
            $result = $query->fetch();
            return new BlogPost($result["id"], $result["title"], $result["permalink"], $result["post_full"], $result["post_sample"], $result["tags"], $result["timestamp"]);
            break;
        }

        case "number": {
            $query = $inDatabase->prepare("select * from blog_posts 
                order by :order 
                limit :limit_start , :limit_end");
            $query->bindParam(":order", $inOrder);
            $splitLimits = explode(", ", $inFilter);
            if (sizeOf($splitLimits) === 1)
                $splitLimits[] = 1; // First post

            $limitEnd = $splitLimits[0] + $limitStart;
            $limitStart = $splitLimits[1] - 1;
            $query->bindValue(":limit_start", (int) $limitStart, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $query->bindValue(":limit_end", (int) $limitEnd, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $query->debugDumpParams();
            $query->execute();
            $results = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $return = array();
            foreach ($results as $result) {
                $return[] = new BlogPost($result["id"], $result["title"], $result["permalink"], $result["post_full"], $result["post_sample"], $result["tags"], $result["timestamp"]);
            }
            return $return;
            break;
        }

        case "id": {
            $query = $inDatabase->prepare("select * from blog_posts where id = :id order by :order");
            $query->bindParam(":id", $inFilter);
            $query->bindParam(":order", $inOrder);
            $query->execute();
            return $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // Prevents duplicate results when using loops (foreach, while etc.)
            break;
        }

        case "date": {
            $splitdate = explode(", ", $inFilter);
            $query = $inDatabase->prepare("select * from blog_posts 
                where (date_posted > :newerthan_date) 
                and (date_posted <= :olderthan_date) 
                order by :order");
            if (sizeof($splitdate) === 1) {
                $splitdate[] = date("Y-m-d");
            }
            $query->bindParam(":newerthan_date", $splitdate[0]);
            $query->bindParam(":olderthan_date", $splitdate[1]);
            $query->bindParam(":order", $inOrder);
            $query->execute();
            return $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            break;
        }

        case "tag": {
            $tags = explode(", ", $inFilter);
            $insert = "";
            foreach ($tags as $key => $tag) {
                if ($key === 0) {
                    $insert .= "where tags like :tag_{$key}";
                }
                else {
                    $insert .= " or tags like :tag_{$key}";
                }
            }

            $query = $inDatabase->prepare("select * from blog_posts
                {$insert} 
                order by :order");

            foreach ($tags as $key => $tag) {
                $query->bindValue(":tag_{$key}", '%^' . $tag . '^%');
            }

            $query->bindParam(":order", $inOrder);
            $query->execute();
            return $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

On the main page, `$results = getBlogPosts("number", $sql_conn, "10", "timestamp desc");` is called and a foreach loop iterates through the posts. The problem is that PDO does not seem to be applying the `:order` parameter; whatever I put for $inOrder it always has the same order. If I go and directly change the statement within the `getBlogPosts` function to have `order by timestamp desc` instead of `order by :order`, it works fine.

I'm stumped - any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"This parameter is fed directly into the query and therefore should be raw SQL."* => the comment is correct, the code is **not**, fix this. The reason is you can specify strings/numbers/etc. with parameters, but *not*  identifiers (column names etc.).

What your query does it this:

```
 SELECT ... FROM ... ORDER BY 'columnname';
```

Rather then:

```
 SELECT ... FROM ... ORDER BY columnname;
```

So. it sorts by the string `'columnname'`, not the value in the field with the same name, with is the same for every row, so no sorting takes place (you might as well `ORDER BY 1`. The solution here is to add that order by clause as raw MySQL as the docblock comment states. If you want more control over it / prevent nastiness there, you could provide a whitelist of allowable order by clauses and refuse others.

Comment: Thanks, I wrote this function a while ago, I had forgotten about that!